# Calling functions with Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

**What I want to achieve**
I have some works I want to show. So, I have thumbnails of these. When a visitor clicks on a thumbnail, I want a div (called slickbox) to open and show the title, the description and a slider about the work clicked.

**What I've already done and how**
I get my work's datas from a database. Here is the little part of my listing of works:

index.php

```
<?php
  $retour_messages = mysql_query('SELECT 2K13_works.*, 2K13_categories.nom AS nomCAT FROM 2K13_works, 2K13_categories WHERE 2K13_works.cat_id = 2K13_categories.cat_id ORDER BY 2K13_works.record_date DESC') or die(mysql_error());//requete sql pour récupérer les works de la page
  ?>
  <ul id = "creations" class = "step">
    <?php
  while($donnees_messages=mysql_fetch_assoc($retour_messages)){
  echo '<li class = "step '.$donnees_messages['nomCAT'].'" id="'.$donnees_messages['work_id'].'">
               <div class = "item"><a href = "#"><img src = "'.$donnees_messages['thumbLink'].'" alt = "'.$donnees_messages['titre'].'" title = "" width = "226" height = "147"/></a>
                <div class = "caption">
                  <h3>'.$donnees_messages['titre'].'</h3>
                  <p>'.html_entity_decode($donnees_messages['resume'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8').'</p>
                  <p id = "desc" class = "hidden">'.html_entity_decode($donnees_messages['description'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8').'</p>
                  <!--<p id = "idw" class = "hidden">'.$donnees_messages['work_id'].'</p>-->
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>';
            }
 ?>
  </ul>
```

As you can see, I have a ul tag containing a li tagfor each work. Each li tag takes the id of the work in database, and each li contains h3 tag and p tag containing the texts I want to show in a slickbox (for the images, I'll see later).

Now, my JavaScript code for the slickbox, appearing and disappearing:

front_functions.js

```
//_____________SLICKBOX__________________________________
$('#slickbox').hide();
$("#creations li").click(function(e) {
    // shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link
    $titre = $(e.target).children("h3").text();
    $bla = $(e.target).children("#hidden").text();
    $("#description").children("h1").text($titre) ;
    $("#description").children("p").text($bla); 
      $('#slickbox').slideDown();
      e.preventDefault();
      $(e.target).empty();
      //return false;
});
```

This code is not working, because my slickbox is loaded before the works. So that's why I need Ajax and a asynchronous way of sending and executing requests.

I read this sample code here: [which is quite helpful](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php).
But, I have a problem: I'm using jQuery and I would like to use `$.ajax()`. And I just don't really understand how to do this.

Do I have to set an XHMLHTTPRequest object? Where can I write the Ajax call? Can I call a function, instead of an URL?

Like doing (I don't know):

```
$(#creations li).click(function(e){
        $.ajax(){
           function : "displayContent(id,desc,title)",
        }
}
function displayContent(id,desc,title){
    $(#slickBox).children("h1").innerHTML(title);
    $(#slickBox).children("p").innerHTML(desc);
    $(#slickBox).show();
}
```

I don't even know if I should use JSON (but, well, because my data is already stored, and I just want to display them, I think I don't need Json).

Please give me your informed opinion and your senior advice.

Comment: Asynchronous programming (which AJAX is) tends to involves *callbacks*. If you look at the `$.ajax` syntax, you provide a function to be called as a parameter. You can do it like `$.ajax({ success: function(data) { ... }})`.

Comment: thanks @WaleedKhan ! i'll try it and come back if i have questions or thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you send a request for server (with ajax) this is like that you are submitting a form in a page .
so every thing that you can do with php when a form submitted , you can do that with ajax too .
e.g if you want to call a function in php with ajax , just send a param to php like this :

```
$.ajax({  
  type:'POST',
  data:{
     param:'Hey_php_call_this_function' 
  },
  success:function(data){
     alert('hey jquery , php said : ' + data);
  }
});
```

and in server side :

```
if(isset($_POST['param']) && $_POST['param'] == 'Hey_php_call_this_function'){
    echo call_a_function();  /// "output to callback success function"  = data
}
```

hope that helpful .

Comment: thanks @Mb Rostami, this is a little explanation I can understand :)
I'll try to write it down my code, i'll come back if i have more questions/a solution.
Thanks again for yout time!

Comment: Well, i Started to work it, and well, it gives me pretty good results. I just have a lot of issues with json_encode, to get an array with results, but i think i can handle it with my friend google.
Another Thanks to YOU @Mb Rostami!